# Can't force HTTP to HTTPS on .htaccess file

Tags: .htaccess, http, ssl, https

I have been asked to make a website secure by trying to force the HHTP to HTTPS (i didn't build it originally), I have tried the following code in the .htaccess file and it messes up the webpage,(its all new to me and I have included the original code also , just need to know where is should put the new code and what I should remove(if anything)

**New code to add**

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} charm-music\.co\.uk [NC]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.charm-music.co.uk/$1 [R,L]
```

**Original .htaccessfile**

```
# Use PHP5.4 as default
AddHandler application/x-httpd-ea-php56 .php
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^charm-music.co.uk
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/acme-challenge/[0-9a-zA-Z_-]+$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/cpanel-dcv/[0-9a-zA-Z_-]+$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/pki-validation/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.charm-music.co.uk/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/acme-challenge/[0-9a-zA-Z_-]+$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/cpanel-dcv/[0-9a-zA-Z_-]+$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/pki-validation/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
RewriteRule .* index.php/$0 [PT,L]
```

I'm thinking its more to do with the code already installed on the file but I don't know what to replace or remove or where I should add the above code, any info greatly appreciated.

Cheers Andy

Comment: So is not the proper place to ask server related question. Well have your server installed SSL?

Comment: soory,where should i post this question please,yes SSL is installed and working just the website shows ,not secure,no padlock so just wondering why the code ive tried isnt working in the .htaccess file

Comment: SSL  installed from SSLforfree, right?

Comment: ssl was supplied by Just Host free ssl on the server,its shows to be working as another site i have has no issues,i just think its the website developers code which is causing the issue and i don't know what platform they used. Was hopinf it was a quick fix

Comment: ssl issued by justhost webhosting company

Comment: The existing code has a redirect for any request (with a few explicitly defined exceptions) with the host name `charm-music.co.uk` to the `www.`-prefixed version, but that’s an explicit redirect to HTTP. That should be made HTTPS to begin with, at least. (And if this doesn’t solve your problem already, then we first of all need a _proper_ problem description from you. _“and it messes up the webpage”_ is not one. Please go read [ask].)